# What's Cloud formation SSHLocation syntax?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-cloudformation

```json
"SSHLocation" : {
      "Description" : "The IP address range that can SSH to the EC2 instance.",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
   }
  }
```

Can you please help me to understand this syntax? Like: What is maximum and minimum length? And what is this `AllowedPattern` syntax and how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

The snippet in your Question represents a `Parameter`. This is a value being passed into the template.

It is basically saying:

- Parameter name: `SSHLocation`
- It will be stored as a **string**
- The user is allowed to provide a string from **9-18 characters**
- The default string will be `0.0.0.0.0/0`
- If the user types something, it will be checked against a regex string that will be:

  - 1-3 digits + a dot (`.`) + 1-3 digits + a dot (`.`) + 1-3 digits + a dot (`.`) + a slash (`/`) + 1-2 digits

It is basically asking for a [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cidr), which is a way of specifying a range of IP addresses.

Based on the description ("The IP address range that can SSH to the EC2 instance."), it would likely be used as a setting later in the CloudFormation template for specifying an **inbound rule on a security group that permits SSH access (port 22)**.

Answer (score 0):

This is for **CIDR range** which is allowed to make ssh connections to your instance/database or whatever you have in your template. For example:

- `0.0.0.0/0` - all possible IPv4 addresses
- `123.4.1.22/32` - only one specific address `123.4.1.22`
- `10.0.1.0/24` - subnet range, `10.0.1.0` - `10.0.1.255`

You can read more about CIDRs [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).